# htaccess redirect domain and mask url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, webserver

I want to redirect a domain name : http://www.newdomain.com to http://sub.maindomain.com

I have edited .htaccess as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub.maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.maindomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It redirects but the http://sub.maindomain.com visible in the address bar . Help! How to do the masking so that http://www.newdomain.com would be visible . Thanks

And also I want create a subsite http://sub.newdomain.com . How to do it with .htaccess .

Comment: Are `www.newdomain.com` and `sub.maindomain.com` served by the same host?

Comment: @JonLin No they are being served by different hosts . But I don't think its really matters if its same or different .

Comment: If you have redirect (the `R=301` flag or having `http://`/`https://` in the rule's target), then the browser will always show the new URL in the address bar. If they are on 2 different hosts, then you can't internally rewrite, you can only redirect or proxy.

Comment: Is there any way I could do it with php . They are in a different host and I want 'www.newdomain.com' to be displayed rather than 'sub.maindomain.com' .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `www.newdomain.com` and `sub.maindomain.com` are on different hosts, the only way to get the content on `sub.maindomain.com` to be served while the browser's URL address bar says `www.newdomain.com` is to fetch the content from `sub.maindomain.com` *on behalf of the browser*. Since as far as the browser is concerned, it's looking at content on newdomain.

You can do this either by setting up a proxy using apache or maybe a script. Using apache, you'd need access to your vhost config for the `www.newdomain.com` domain. You can set it up like:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(.*)$ http://sub.maindomain.com$1
```

Take a look at the [mod_proxy docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for more info on the flags you can pass this directive, to tweak timeouts and retries.

If you want to setup a php script to proxy, you'll need to route all requests to this php script, so in your htaccess file in your `www.newdomain.com` document root, add (assuming this php script is called `proxy.php`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/proxy.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proxy.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in `proxy.php`, look for the `url` query string, load that page, and output it to the browser.

Though all of this is much easier if you can just point both domains to the same host.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this descriptive answer .

Comment: Could describe me how to create a subsite http://sub.newdomain.com .Is it possible with .htaccess . It would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Subhransu A couple of examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929129/can-i-dynamically-create-subdomains-php-htaccess-with-godaddy-hosting http://stackoverflow.com/a/874802/851273 http://stackoverflow.com/a/3126695/851273

Comment: Could you help me out with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631500/not-redirecting-the-subdomain-using-htaccess) . Thanks for being so generous .