# Not redirecting the subdomain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have site which uses wordpress and I usually login as : mydomain.com/wp-admin . I want it to be on the subdomain .
I have tried to create a subdomain by using the following rewrite url :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp-admin/$1 [L]
```

But when I am trying to reach`http://wp-admin.mydomain.com/` a weired page comes out saying  an error message :

`If you feel you have reached this page in error, please contact the web site owner:`

And the url changes to :

```
http://wp-admin.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

Please help how could I be able to create a subdomain .

Comment: Can you five more details on that “weird page”? Do the server error logs provide more detail on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to give an absolute path, and to enforce an internal redirect (aka. [pass-through](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)).

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-admin/$1 [PT,L]
                   ^             ^^
```